# Can I disable censorship in the German version of Fallout 3?

Tags: fallout-3

Recently, I purchased Fallout 3 on Steam, at a very reduced price. I was not paying attention, though, and I got a German copy.

Playing the game in German is fine, as I speak it, but Mature content is disabled. Is there any way to enable it?

Comment: Because I don't live in Germany, I'm having difficulty understanding what mature content is disabled exactly. The blood and strong language?

Comment: @TimmyJim, based on google searches for this, it looks like blood and gore is completely removed. Bloody Mess -> Bloodless Backflips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure this will work since I have been reading mixed messages about it. But there is an ini tweak you might be able to make in order to enable the blood and gore in the german version.

**From Tweek Guides**

> bDisableAllGore=1 - If set to =1, this variable will disable all gore in the game. This includes removing all blood decals and splatter marks, and all forms of dismemberment. Note: This setting does not exist by default in the .ini file, it must be manually created exactly as shown above and placed under the [General] section of the Fallout.ini file (e.g. insert it under the last sLanguage=ENGLISH line). If on the other hand you want more control over the level gore, try a mod such as this Gore Tweak Mod (Fallout.ini).

Source: http://www.tweakguides.com/Fallout3_8.html

Comment: Give me an update when you try it. The German version of FO3 seems to be quite an odd version of it.

Comment: You should use `bDisableAllGore=0` right?

Comment: Yeah 0 would say that you do not want to disable it. It might not work though the German version is really odd.